# At/in/within any time range

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of the following should I say

> At any time range, report A has a higher total than report B.
>
> In any time range, report A has a higher total than report B.
>
> Within any time range, report A has a higher total than report B.

Also should I say time range or time frame in this case? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you provide additional context? Not only could any of these be valid, but I could also see *for any time range*, *on any time range*, *with any time range*, *through any time range*, etc.

Comment: @choster that's the entire statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'At' should be used with singular times; not with ranges, which have two ends.  'Within' adds some nuance to 'in' that reinforces the notion of range.  A range of time is commonly a '[time] period'.

Answer (score 3):

Of the three examples you've listed,

> "Within any time range, report A has a higher total than report B,"

sounds the most natural to me. Either "time range" or "time frame" is acceptable; "time frame" is more familiar, but "time range" sounds more scientific. In both cases, these are just my personal preferences.